# SVG chart is converted wrong with Canvg

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, html5-canvas, canvg

When I try to convert a svg chart with Canvg, the bars of the char are missing. I think the problem might be that the svg is attached to the canvas before the bars animations are executed.

```
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = svgElement.clientWidth;
  canvas.height = svgElement.clientHeight;

  const svg = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgElement);

  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  const canvgView = await Canvg.fromString(ctx, svg);
  await canvgView.render();
```

[image: Missing bars]

Comment: svgElement is a `<svg>` html element.

Comment: http://pastie.org/p/1EVbeufj1FrYbphvevPegc

Comment: I can't reproduce. Works fine for me. https://codepen.io/ggorlen/pen/LYbbzbo. Please provide a [mcve] as a [runnable stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).